# How to choose GPU device for XGBoost in python

Tags: python, gpu, xgboost

I'm running XGBoost (eXtreme Gradient Boosting) in Python on a shared linux server, which is equipped with multiple GPUs. When I run XGBoost on a GPU, XGBoost automatically selects GPU device 0. Does anybody know how I can make XGBoost to select another GPU? (gpu0 is normally too busy )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the source code, it turned out that it can be chosen in the constructor of the class by assigning the gpu device number to *gpu_id*. E.g.,

```
xgb.XGBClassifier(tree_method='gpu_hist',predictor='gpu_predictor',gpu_id=1)
```